# Android: prevent user from coming back to login page after logging in

Tags: android, cookies, authentication

I have a login page in my android app. I want to prevent the user after logging in to come back to the login page. Also, when the user reopens the app, if he has logged in before, I want to go directly to the main page without having to go to the login page.

What the best way of doing that? One idea I thought of is to save the login parameters in a cookie, and then, when the app is reopens, if the cookie contains some login information, I inflate the main page, otherwise, I inflate the login page. Is this the best way of doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: The best way of doing that is probably to write some Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Before displaying login dialog/activity just check in your preferences presence of special flag:

```
Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
boolean isLogged=settings.getBoolean("isLogged", false);
```

Depending on `isLogged` value you can redirect either to login or other page

2) Somewhere in your login page after logging save `isLogged` status, like:

```
Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
editor.commit();
```

That's all folks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm

Comment: Hi I got an issue with this code. after main activity opened after login. I couldn't quit from my apps. because when I press back button it will go to `LoginActivity` and there's `isLogged` checking within the activity so the app let me to the `MainActivity` again.

Comment: Could you please specify what is PREFERENCES in the code.

Comment: String specifying name of preferences file, like - "myprefs"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Store a value as soon as the user has loged in. Based on that value, you show your login activity or your main activity.

You could also use a SQLite database, or the file system to store stuff permanently.