# Leaked window decor on alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am newbie to understand this type of error. I am unable to understand this. I clsose all the function before change activity but there are still facing same prolem.
Here is my code. And I am unable to solve this error.

```
         private void versionChecker() {
        VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker(SplashActivity.this);

        try {
            latestVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
            Log.d(TAG, "latestVersion: " + latestVersion);
//            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), latestVersion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (latestVersion != null) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d(TAG, "latest:  " + version);
            Log.d(TAG, "latestVersion: " + latestVersion);
            if (version.equals(latestVersion)) {
                startWithDelay();

            } else {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, viewGroup, false);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", (dialog, which) -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();
//                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
//                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
//                                    + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
//                    finish();

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Deny",(dialog, which) -> {
                    if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    startWithDelay();

                });




                        builder.setView(dialogView);
                        alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();


            }


        } else {
//            try {
//                Log.d(TAG, "url:" + urlObject);
//                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
//                i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
//                i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
//                i.setData(Uri.parse(urlObject));
//                startActivity(i);
//            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                // Chrome is not installed
//                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlObject));
//                startActivity(i);
//            }
                     Toast.makeText(this, "to do for url coding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//            startWithDelay();
        }

    }

    private void startWithDelay() {
//        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        if (signnedIn.equals("true")  &&  loggedIn.equals("true")){

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();

        }else {

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FirstActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

//        },3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (alertDialog != null){
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (alertDialog != null){
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.atomsgroup.firstaim.Activity.SplashActivity has leaked window DecorView@a9f6556[SplashActivity] that was originally added here
```

**I tried**
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862569/window-leak-due-to-alert-dialog)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) and more.

Here I has been added alert dialog dismiss on destroy and pause but Logcat showing same error.Stack overflow have lots of question with this type of error but I am still unable to find my error.

**UPDATE**
Here is my versionCheker Class

```
    public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {


    private String newVersion;
    private Context context;

    public VersionChecker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Log.d("resDoc", String.valueOf(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
//            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en"
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();


            if (document != null) {
                Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                for (Element ele : element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                        for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                            newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `VersionChecker` class? Is it a `Dialog` or something?

Comment: It is class get version from play store of my app

Comment: Make sure you're not displaying any dialog from that class using your **activity context**.

Comment: I updated my answer with my version checker class

Comment: You're referencing **context** as global variable in `AsyncTask` and it's where issue happens. Try not to reference it and remove if not in used or else make it as `WeakReference`.

Comment: Can you show me How can I do that because when I make empty constructor of version checker it shows same error. I do not know I am doing right and wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193459/discussion-between-jeel-vankhede-and-blackblind).